# Hook automatic_updates_complete to autoupdate plugin

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions, automatic-updates

I'm trying to trigger some internal update class when WP is autoupdated.
For manual update (when clicking on update), I found a way, it's pretty well documentated, I use the hook

`add_action( 'uprader_process_complete', 'my_update_function', 10, 2)`

However, when using the

`add_action( 'automatic_updates_complete', 'my_update_function', 10, 1)` 
It is not executed.

Is there anyone using an update function in its wordpress plugin? Documentation is pretty scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
function my_function_to_run_on_autoupdate(array $results ): void {
        // Iterate through the plugins being updated and check if ours is there.
        foreach ( $results['plugin'] as $plugin ) {

            if ( 
                isset( $plugin->item->slug )
                && strlen( $plugin->item->slug ) > 0
                // 'your-plugin-slug' is usually the folder name of your plugin
                && $plugin->item->slug === 'your-plugin-slug'
            ) {
                // Run whatever you want to run
            }

        }

}
```

This will be executed every time there is a plugin auto-update. If it finds your plugin, the code in "if" will be executed.